# Struggling with this mixed, nested set of objects

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I am still trying to get to grips with nested objects within Python and have come a bit unstruck trying to extract what I want from this data structure (which is returned from a website XHR request using the .json() method):

```
 {u'statColumns': [u'apps', u'subOn', u'minsPlayed', u'assistCross', u'assistCorner', 
u'assistThroughball', u'assistFreekick', u'assistThrowin', u'assistOther', u'assist'], u'paging': 
{u'firstRecordIndex': 0, u'resultsPerPage': 0, u'lastRecordIndex': 0, u'totalPages': 0,
 u'currentPage': 1, u'totalResults': 0}, u'teamTableStats': [{u'seasonId': 0, u'ranking': 1,
 u'assistFreekick': 0.0, u'minsPlayed': 810, u'tournamentName': u'Premier League', u'rating': 
7.35092043142043, u'assistThroughball': 0.4444444444444444, u'tournamentRegionCode': None, u'apps': 
9, u'seasonName': None, u'teamName': u'Chelsea', u'tournamentRegionId': 252, u'regionCode': u'gb-
eng', u'teamId': 15, u'assistThrowin': 0.0, u'assistCorner': 0.3333333333333333, u'tournamentId': 2,
 u'assistOther': 1.0, u'assistCross': 0.5555555555555556, u'assist': 0.0, u'name': u'Chelsea'},

    ...
    ...
    ...
     {u'seasonId': 0, u'ranking': 19, u'assistFreekick': 0.0, u'minsPlayed': 810, u'tournamentName':
 u'Premier League', u'rating': 6.716523569023569, u'assistThroughball': 0.1111111111111111, 
u'tournamentRegionCode': None, u'apps': 9, u'seasonName': None, u'teamName': u'Burnley', 
u'tournamentRegionId': 252, u'regionCode': u'gb-eng', u'teamId': 184, u'assistThrowin': 0.0, 
u'assistCorner': 0.0, u'tournamentId': 2, u'assistOther': 0.2222222222222222, u'assistCross': 0.0, 
u'assist': 0.0, u'name': u'Burnley'}, {u'seasonId': 0, u'ranking': 20, u'assistFreekick': 0.0, 
u'minsPlayed': 810, u'tournamentName': u'Premier League', u'rating': 6.681928256928256, 
u'assistThroughball': 0.0, u'tournamentRegionCode': None, u'apps': 9, u'seasonName': None, 
u'teamName': u'Aston Villa', u'tournamentRegionId': 252, u'regionCode': u'gb-eng', u'teamId': 24, 
u'assistThrowin': 0.0, u'assistCorner': 0.0, u'tournamentId': 2, u'assistOther': 0.2222222222222222,
 u'assistCross': 0.0, u'assist': 0.0, u'name': u'Aston Villa'}]}
```

This is the XML HTTP request that populates a table on a website containing football data. The data can be recut/refreshed/repopulated using drop downs on the website. The table contains data for 20 teams in the Premier League.

What I want is the contents of the list of dictionaries that is called `u'teamTableStats':` within the larger nested structure. Each dictionary within this corresponds to one team's data.

I have tried using the code (where responser is the object returned using .json():

```
for match in responser:

    print "match = ", match
```

This returns a result like this:

```
match =  statColumns
match =  paging
match =  teamTableStats
```

When what I actually want would be this:

```
{u'seasonId': 0, u'ranking': 1,
     u'assistFreekick': 0.0, u'minsPlayed': 810, u'tournamentName': u'Premier League', u'rating': 
    7.35092043142043, u'assistThroughball': 0.4444444444444444, u'tournamentRegionCode': None, u'apps': 
    9, u'seasonName': None, u'teamName': u'Chelsea', u'tournamentRegionId': 252, u'regionCode': u'gb-
    eng', u'teamId': 15, u'assistThrowin': 0.0, u'assistCorner': 0.3333333333333333, u'tournamentId': 2,
     u'assistOther': 1.0, u'assistCross': 0.5555555555555556, u'assist': 0.0, u'name': u'Chelsea'}
...
...
...
{u'seasonId': 0, u'ranking': 20, u'assistFreekick': 0.0, 
    u'minsPlayed': 810, u'tournamentName': u'Premier League', u'rating': 6.681928256928256, 
    u'assistThroughball': 0.0, u'tournamentRegionCode': None, u'apps': 9, u'seasonName': None, 
    u'teamName': u'Aston Villa', u'tournamentRegionId': 252, u'regionCode': u'gb-eng', u'teamId': 24, 
    u'assistThrowin': 0.0, u'assistCorner': 0.0, u'tournamentId': 2, u'assistOther': 0.2222222222222222,
     u'assistCross': 0.0, u'assist': 0.0, u'name': u'Aston Villa'}
```

Where the dictionary containing for the data for each team is returned. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and what syntax I should use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`jsonObject[u'teamTableStats']` will give you the list of dictionaries corresponding to teamTableStats.

Then just iterate through them and do what you want with them:

```
teamStatDicts = jsonObject[u'teamTableStats']
for statDict in teamStatDicts:
    print "match =", statDict
```